# Altering relationship in Views contextually

Tags: views, nodes

I need to alter a Views relationship contextually: since the View is embedded into another node, the relationship is defined by a field's value of a parent node.

I presume the only way to add a relationship is using hook_views_data_alter, but I'm not quite sure if it's going to work inside a preprocessor function (I'm creating a View for a certain node type) and what's the proper way of using it. The related field will be a Nodequeue instance (Nodequeue module is integrated with Views using relationships), its name will be contained in that parent node's field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually discover simple solution, so perhaps it comes in handy for anyone else later. views_data_alter, of course, is not meant to apply an existing relationship, but rather to create a new one. To apply an existing relationship programmatically - Nodequeque in my case - you need to call in add_item function of view class:

```
$view->add_item($view->current_display, 'relationship', 'node', 'nodequeue_rel', array('names'=>array('myqueue'=>'myqueue'), 'required'=>1, 'limit'=>1))
```

where an array is a set of options like: the name(s) of queue(s) and whether any nodes excluded from chosen queque(s) should be added (1 - bool - implies that only nodes inside the chosen queque will be added).